# Dajax/Dajaxice saving object in ajax.py with parameters

Tags: python, django, jquery, dajaxice, dajax

I've run through setup and have all examples on dajaxproject.com running fine, but I'm now having problems using what I've learnt in a more complex use case. I'd like to pass several parameters to the ajax function, along with text from a form, and create an object using those pieces of data.

If anybody can help me out, it would be hugely appreciated.

I'm using jquery and jquery.ba-serializeobject.min.js.

**Ajax.py:**

```
@dajaxice_register
def save_comment(req, form, user_username, other_username):
    dajax = Dajax()
    comment_form = CreateCommentForm(deserialize_form(form))
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        text = comment_form.cleaned_data['text']
        user = User.objects.get(username=user_username)
        other_user = User.objects.get(username=other_username)
        other_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=other_user)
        comment = other_profile.comments.objects.create(owner=user, text=text)
        comment.save()
        return dajax.json()
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function add_comment(){
          var user = '{{ person.user.username }}';
          var other = '{{ other.user.username }}';
          var data = $('#comment_form').serialize(true);
          Dajaxice.profiles.save_comment(Dajax.process, {'form': data, 'user_username': user, 'other_username': other });
          return false;
        }
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div><h4>Post Comment:</h4>
                <div id="comment_form_errors"></div>
                <form action="" id="comment_form" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {{ commentform.as_p }}

                    <p><input class="btn profile-comment-submit" id="submit_profile_comment" onclick="add_comment()" type="submit" alt="register" /></p>
                <form>
            </div>
```

In Chrome's debug console the only error I get is Dajaxice: something went wrong.

If I've left anything out that might be important, let me know.

Many thanks,

Comment: This might be happening because of the way you're creating and passing the JSON object. Please try the JSON.stringify() fuction on your data object (var data = JSON.stringify($('#comment_form').serialize(true))). I haven't used JQuery therefore I might be missing something but I have a good reason to suspect that this being caused due to the way you're creating and passing the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that stands out to me (and I'm no expert, so who knows...) is in your ajax.py. I think it should be:

```
@dajaxice_register
def save_comment(req, form, user_username, other_username):
    dajax = Dajax()
    comment_form = CreateCommentForm(deserialize_form(form))
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        text = comment_form.cleaned_data['text']
        user = User.objects.get(username=user_username)
        other_user = User.objects.get(username=other_username)
        other_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=other_user)
        comment = Comment(owner=user, text=text)
        comment.save()
        other_profile.comments.add(comment)
        # I don't think you need to other_profile.save(), but you can if you want
        return dajax.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you send the form is crusial for Dajax to work. I have succeeded using http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject and the following javascript:

```
jQuery('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
    var data = jQuery(this).serializeObject();
    Dajaxice.app.app_name.function_name(Dajax.process,{'form':data});
    return false;
});
```

It is a little hard to get a complete overview of the problem when I don't see your form. But I would recommend you to create a form CommentForm and populate user and other_user in hidden fields on form initialization. That will make the code less complex

Your save function will then be quite simple:

```
@dajaxice_register
def function_name(request, form):
   dajax = Dajax()

   form = CommentForm(form)

   if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
   return dajax.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I can see here, but without being able to see the `CreateCommentForm()` and the model that it is creating a form for some of this may be assumption based.  Also assuming there are not any problems with the serialization of the form.

```
@dajaxice_register
def save_comment(req, form, user_username, other_username):
    dajax = Dajax()

    user = User.objects.get(username=user_username)
    other_user = User.objects.get(username=other_username)
    other_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=other_user)

    # Required fields of a form must be checked before calling is_valid() or is_valid fails.
    comment = Comments(owner=user)
    comment_form = CreateCommentForm(deserialize_form(form), instance=comment)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        comment_form.save()
        dajax.alert('Form is valid')
    else:
        dajax.alert('Form is invalid')
        for error in comment_form.errors:
            dajax.add_css_class('#id_%s' % error, 'error')

    # Dajax needs something added to it before the dajax.json() can be returned.
    return dajax.json()
```

The form piece can be referred to here: [Django using a subset of fields on the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form)
and the dajax return pieces can be seen in more detail in this dajax example: [Dajax form validation example](http://www.dajaxproject.com/fullform/)

Answer (score 0):

I've found no way to make it work. I think it is an issue with Dajaxice, what you can do is to avoid the request.POST QueryDict and instead use the request.raw_post_data. You'll need to do the reverse of urlparse:

```
data = urlparse.parse_qs(request.raw_post_data)
```

Then you'll need to deserialize it.

```
data = json.loads(data.get('argv'))
```

That will return a list of arguments, use the first element in the list.